# Which of the following functions on $\mathbb{R}$ are distribution functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**(a)** $F(x) = I_{(2, \infty)}(x)$

**(b)** $F(x)= \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$.

I know for F to be a distribution function it must follow the following properties:

**(i)**  $0 \leq F(x) \leq 1;$

**(ii)** $x \leq y \rightarrow F(x) \leq F(y);$

**(iii)** $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 
F(x)=1$

For **(a)**, I don't know what I stands for, so I tried googling it and I couldn't find it, so if someone can explain to me what I is then I can try working it out.

**(b)** Will not be a distribution function

**(i)** We can see that $0 \leq \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \leq 1$

**(ii)** Here we can see that $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \leq \frac{y^2}{1+y^2}$

**(iii)** If we take the $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ we get $\frac{\frac{x^2}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{x^2}{x^2}} \rightarrow 1$. But if we get $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} =1 \neq 0$.

The book only mentions I in one part: "Let 
$A \subset \Omega$. The indicator function of A is the function  $$I_A(\omega)= \begin{cases}
  1, & w \in A, \\
  0, & w \notin A
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Where does this question come from? If it's a textbook, that's presumably a better reference for the notation than Google.

Comment: my guess is the indicator function on the interval $(2,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $I_A(x),$ where $A$ is a set of real numbers, usually means a function that has the value $I_A(x) = 1$ when $x \in A$ and
$I_A(x) = 0$ when $x \not\in A.$

This is sometimes called an "indicator" function (which "indicates" whether $x$ is member of the set), which I think is why the function is written with the letter $I.$

In the function named $I_{(2,\infty)},$ the set $A$ is the interval $(2,\infty).$ Hence the function says whether $x \in (2,\infty).$

Notice that your answer to (b)(iii) shows that your answer to (b)(ii) is wrong.
Indeed, if $0 \leq x \leq y$ then $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \leq \frac{y^2}{1+y^2},$
but not if $x \leq y \leq 0.$
Try $x = -2, y=-1$ for example.

Comment: Ah I should of seen of the case $x \leq y \leq 0$. that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 
$$
I_{(2,\infty)}(x)=\chi_{(2,\infty)}(x)
$$
or a function that outputs 1 on the interval $(2,\infty)$ and zero elsewhere, the conditions in your problem are trivially met.

Answer (score 1):

(a) This is the indication function: $I_{(2,\infty)}(x)$ is the function that takes value $1$ for $2 < x < + \infty$ and $0$ elsewhere. This is the c.d.f. for the degenerate r.v. that takes value $2$ with probability 1.

(b) (ii) fails for $x,y<0$, but works if $x,y \ge 0$. Likewise, (iii) holds if the lower bound of the support is 0. Briefly, the function is not a c.f.d. on $(-\infty, + \infty)$ but it is on the support $(0, +\infty)$.